# HttpWebRequest in UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I'm writing code to make HttpWebRequest to website

if website is working it will return `HttpStatusCode.OK`

if not it will return `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`

My code

```
 var url = "http://simplegames.com.ua/";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("All ok");
        }
        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("URL not working");
        }
        response.Close();
```

But i have errors

> 1) Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetResponse' and no extension method 'GetResponse' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\MainPage.xaml.cs    50  Active
>
> 2) Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1929  'HttpWebResponse' does not contain a definition for
>   'Close' and the best extension method overload
>   'ExtensionMethods.Close(Stream)' requires a receiver of type
>   'Stream'  Milano  C:\Users\nemes\Documents\GitHub\Milano_pizza\Milano\MainPage.xaml.cs    59  Active

Comment: Did you get that error on build, or just when writing it out?  Have you tried exiting Visual Studio completely and coming back in?  Sometimes VS gets confused.

Comment: Yes.I tried this@JeremyHolovacs

Comment: Do you have another class called `HttpWebRequest` in your code or namespace?

Comment: Nope. Maybe in uwp it need to be write differently? @JeremyHolovacs

Comment: In general, I think you'd want to use an `HttpClient` instead of an `HttpWebRequest` for UWP, but I don't know if that will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes, HttpClient solved problem @JeremyHolovacs

Answer (score 5):

Although we can use [HttpWebRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) in UWP apps, but not all of its methods. [HttpWebRequest.GetResponse method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) and [HttpWebResponse.Close Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.close(v=vs.110).aspx) are the methods that can't be used in UWP apps. Usually, we can find if a method can be used in UWP apps by checking the **Version Information** in the bottom of the document. If we can find **Universal Windows Platform** under **Version Information** then we should be able to use this method in UWP apps.

In .NET Core/UWP, **System.Net.HttpWebRequest class** is in **System.Net.Requests** library and is not recommended to use. Ref. [.NET Networking APIs for UWP Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/28/net-networking-apis-for-uwp-apps/):

> **System.Net.Requests**
>
> This library contains types related to **System.Net.HttpWebRequest** and **System.Net.HttpWebResponse** classes that allow developers to implement the client role of the HTTP protocol. The API surface for .NET Core 5 is the same as that available for Windows 8.1 apps and is very **limited** compared to the surface in the .NET Framework. This is **intentional** and we **highly encourage** switching to the **HttpClient API** instead – that is where our energy and innovation will be focused going forward.
>
> This library is provided purely for backward compatibility and to unblock usage of .NET libraries that use these older APIs. For .NET Core, the implementation of HttpWebRequest is actually based on HttpClient (reversing the dependency order from .NET Framework). As mentioned above, the reason for this is to avoid usage of the managed .NET HTTP stack in a UWP app context and move towards HttpClient as a single HTTP client role API for .NET developers.

And in UWP, we have two **HttpClient APIs**, they are **[System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx)** and **[Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient)**. You can choose either of them according to your requirement. For more info about these two HttpClient APIs, please see [Demystifying HttpClient APIs in the Universal Windows Platform](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/).