# My HttpWebRequest "POST" failed since I upgrade to v5.2.2 of Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (before I used v5.1.0)

Tags: c#, post, uwp, httpwebrequest

I notice something between the v5.2 and 5.1 of the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

I have an APP in v5.1 and a do a "POST" opperation whith a HttpWebRequest , with parameter in the body encode in UTF8. (to simulate a login on a webSite)
If a upgrade to v5.2, my POST stop working !
I restore to v5.1 and it work again !
Have you got an idea ?

**mycode**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlrest.AbsoluteUri); request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
//Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
byte[] postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(allparaminbody); //allparamin_body contain : user=myuser&password=mypassword
request.ContentType = "POST";
request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)";
Stream newStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
newStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
newStream.Dispose();
response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**HttpWebRequest** is not recommended to use in UWP apps. Ref [Demystifying HttpClient APIs in the Universal Windows Platform](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/):

> As a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app developer, if you are trying to communicate over HTTP with a web service or any server endpoint, you have multiple API choices. Two of the most used and recommended APIs for implementing the HTTP client role in a managed UWP app are [**System.Net.Http.HttpClient**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient). These APIs should be **preferred over older, discouraged APIs such as WebClient and HttpWebRequest** (although a small subset of HttpWebRequest is available in UWP for backward compatibility).

Also, you can refer to [my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38871200/5506161). According to your requirement, you can choose either `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` or `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`. And here is a official [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient) on GitHub that uses `Windows.Web.Http` namespace.

Besides, `HttpWebRequest.ContentType` should be the MIME type like `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `text/html`. `POST` ia not a valid value. It should be the value of `HttpWebRequest.Method` Property.

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted Microsoft, there is a BUG in the v5.2, they're going to correct it asap.

=> https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9003

cdt