# How to download an image from local server by url and save as byte array in uwp

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

I am working with an uwp application. In my app I want to download an image from a url which is nothing but local server. After downloading it I want to save the image in byte format in my app data.

I have used this code but getting exception as:
"Invalid port and invalid URI".

the code i used is:

```
HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(img.url);
                        WebResponse imageResponse = await imageRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                        Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

                        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
                        {
                           byte[] imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
                            br.Dispose();
                        }
                        responseStream.Dispose();
                        imageResponse.Dispose();
```

I Tried with httpclient also but getting the same exception.
How can I come out of this.

Comment: "Invalid port and invalid URI" seems to be a pretty clear error message.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38871200/1136211) about the usage of HttpWebRequest in UWP. Better use HttpClient.

Comment: the url is: http:\\\\10.10.0.5:80\\Configurations\\CID8995452\\DenominationImagesFolder\\201701311404332Rupee.png     when I open it in browser the image is displaying

Comment: Replace double backslashes by slashes, like `http://10.10.0.5:80/Configurations...`

Comment: Got it Clemens. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

do not invent the wheel, uwp toolkit has got a nice ImageEx component that can do everything...download, cache, etc...