# C# Rest Requests on UWP

Tags: c#, rest, uwp

I've written code for some Rest-Requests. It works fine on an WPF-App.
Now I want to do the same on an UWP-App (Universal Windows Platform). But there are a lot of problems.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

...

if (this.method == "post")
{
   try
   {
      ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
      byte[] paramData = enc.GetBytes(parameter);

      WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.url);
      request.Method = this.method;
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      request.ContentLength = paramData.Length;

      Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
      stream.Write(paramData, 0, paramData.Length);
      stream.Close();

      WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
      stream = response.GetResponseStream();

      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
      resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();
      sr.Close();
      stream.Close();
   }
}
```

The main problem is that UWP doesn't support 'System.Web'.
Beacuse of that I can't use the Methods '.ContentLength', '.GetRequestStream' and '.GetResponse'.

I've googled a lot but cant find a solution. Othe questions on Stackoverflow didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpWebRequest in UWP (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835974/httpwebrequest-in-uwp-c)

Comment: Aside: Considering using a [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: You can use `HttpClient` for `Post` request using `PostAsync()`